# Parse JSON string in Classic ASP from QueryString (ASP Xtreme Evolution)

Tags: ajax, json, parsing, asp-classic

I have sent a JSON object as a parameter in a QueryString to an ASP  file.
(Currently, the server admin has not updated the IIS settings so I can send POST data).

The string looks like this:

```
{"part":"A7654321","action":"RP"},{"part":"BK2Z-16A470-A","action":"RP"},{"part":"BK2Z-16A470-A","action":"RP"},{"part":"BK2Z-16A470-B","action":"RP"}
```

See the ASP code I am trying to use

```
<!--#include file="json2.asp"-->
<%
obj = Request.QueryString("obj")    'GET JSON OBJ
Response.Write(obj & "</br>")
dim Info : set Info = JSON.parse(obj)
Response.Write(Err.Description)

%>
```

Which outputs the following:

> {"part":"A7654321","action":"RP"},{"part":"BK2Z-16A470-A","action":"RP"},{"part":"BK2Z-16A470-A","action":"RP"},{"part":"BK2Z-16A470-B","action":"RP"}
>
> Object Required

Comment: What does `Response.Write VarType(JSON)` output?

Comment: As an aside: You actually *should* transfer JSON in a POST body instead of an URL parameter, because a) URL parameters are length-limited and b) you might not want that JSON to show up in the IIS log files, but it will if you use GET requests.

Comment: Response.Write(VarType(JSON))

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am just using the GET method until the server admin can setup POST.Response.Write(VarType(JSON)) returns 8

Comment: Okay, then what happe s when you try `Info = JSON.parse(obj)`, i. e. without `Set`?

Comment: I discovered an issue with the preceding code that overwrote the JSON object due to a poor naming choice. Thanks for your help. For anyone curious, the code above is fine as is.

Comment: It is indeed, that's where my "try this/try that" lottery debugging came from. General tip: Never go without `Option Explicit` and avoid global variables as far as possible.